# Validating Non-Model Field in a Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Rails 3.2 app, I have a signup form that includes a "terms and conditions" checkbox. The form looks something like this:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <!-- Error message stuff -->
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <!-- More fields... -->
  <%= text_field_tag :terms_and_conditions, false, "true" %>
<% end %>
```

To make sure the user checks that checkbox, I have the following code in my controller:

```
unless params[:terms_and_conditions] == "true"
  @user.errors[:base] << "You must check the 'Terms and Conditions' checkbox"
end
```

But when I call `@user.save` (or `@user.valid?`), it seems to clear out this error message. I know I could use `@user.errors.empty? && @user.save`, but I find it strange that the `save` method doesn't care about the error message I just added. Is there a better and more elegant way to do this?

Comment: In the controller action or you rendering or redirecting once @user.save returns false. Can you post the rendering code/gist in the controller action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails offers an acceptance validator. It's perfect for your situation. See [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#acceptance) for further information.